# SQL Server group by count eliminate duplicates

Tags: sql-server, group-by

My data is like below:

```
ClassId ClassName   StudentId   Subject     SubjectId  
-----------------------------------------------------
1         ESL        12         English      20  
1         ESL        13         Science      30  
1         ESL        12         Social       40  
1         ESL        12         Maths        50
```

Required output: parameters are Subject column values

```
ClassId ClassName   TotalStudents   SubjectIds   
-----------------------------------------------    
1        ESL         2               20, 40, 50, 30
```

When one student takes multiple subjects then count student only once, so in the above data 12 is one student id takes multiple subjects so counted only once. `TotalStudents` value is 2 (1 from student id 12 and 1 from student id 13)

I wrote this query:

```
Declare @subjectids string  
set @subjectids = '20,30,40,50'  

-- will split @subjectids  and store in temp table     
select 
    classname, classid, Count(Distinct StudentId)  
from 
    mytable  
where 
    SubjectsIds in @subjectIds  
group by 
    ClassId, ClassName, SubjectId,
```

but I get this output:

```
ClassId ClassName   TotalStudents   SubjectIds  
----------------------------------------------    
1        ESL         1               20  
1        ESL         1               30  
1        ESL         1               40  
1        ESL         1               50
```

Any help in eliminating duplicates?
Edited: My basic question is how to count student only once when the same students takes multiple subjects from same class? While counting eliminate duplicates.

Comment: `in` doesn't work with string literals. The proper syntax is `where SubjectsIds in (20,30,40,50)`. But why do you need it anyway?

Comment: do you want comma separated subjectIds?

Comment: I need to count student only once when student takes multiple subjects from same class?